# Send two objects to Django Rest framework with React in frontend but only the lastest one appears in Django Rest framewwork

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a data structure like this in Django Rest Framework:

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Alamos",
        "modeltask": [
                {
                "uid": "1",
                "priority": 1,
                "task": {
                    "time": 0.0,
                    "student": 0 }
                    }
                ,
                   {
                "uid": "2",
                "priority": 2,
                "task": {
                    "time": 0.0,
                    "student": 0 }
                    }
                   ]
```

However even when I send two objects with 2 "uid" as above with React and send it to Django.I checked with React tool for Mozilla and it shows both objects in the front end. However after sending them to backend, there is only the lastest object appears in django rest framework, in the case above is the object with ("uid": "2") only. So I don't know where it goes wrong?

Right now in Django Restful is like this:

```js
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Alamos",
        "modeltask": [
                   {
                "uid": "2",
                "priority": 2,
                "task": {
                    "time": 0.0,
                    "student": 0 }
                    }
                   ]
```

My models.py

```js
class Main(models.Model):
  id= models.AutoField(primary_key=true)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
  def __str__(self):
      return self.name
  @property
  def modeltask(self):
      return self.modeltask_set.all()
class ModelTask(models.Model):
   uid =models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
   priority= models.IntegerField(blank = True, null=True)
   main = models.ForeignKey(Main, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
   def __str__(self):
     return self.uid
class Task(models.Model):
   time = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
   student =models.IntegerField(blank=True, null = True)
```

Here's my serializers.py:

```js
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
            model = Task
            fields =['time', 'student']
class ModelTaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     task = TaskSerializer(required =True)
     class Meta:
            model = ModelTask
            field = ['uid', 'priority', 'student']
     def create(self,validated_data):
            task_data =validated_data.pop('task')
            modeltask = ModelTask.objects.create(**validated_data)
            task.objects.create(**task_data, section =task)
            return modeltask
class MainSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     task = TaskSerializer(many=true)
     class Meta: 
            model = Main
            field = ['id','name','modeltask']
     def create(self,validated_data):
            modeltask = modeltask_data ('modeltask')
            Name = Main.object.create(**validated_data)
            Name.save()
            for data in modeltask:
                task =data.pop('task')
                modeltask_section=ModelTask.objects.create(**data, Name = Name)
     def update(self,instance, validated_data):
            modeltask = validated_data.pop('modeltask')
            instance.name =validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
            instance.save()
            modeltask_id =[]
            for data in modeltask:
                task = data.pop('task')
                for  'id' in data.key():
                    if ModelTask.objects.filter(id =data["id"]).exists():
                       r =Shell.objects.get(id=data["id"])
                       r.uid = data.get("uid",r.uid)
                       r.priority =data.get("priority",r.priority)
                       r.save()
                       Task.objects.create(**task,section=r)
                       modeltask_id.append(r.id)
                    else:
                       instance.modeltask.delete()
                       r =ModelTask.objects.create(**data,Name =instance)
                       Task.objects.create(**task,section =r)
                       modeltask_id.append(r.id)
           for data in instance_modeltask:
                if data.id not in modeltask_id:
                       data.delete()
                       instance.save()
                return instance
```

And views.py

```js
class MainView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     serializer_class = MainSerializer
     queryset = Main.objects.all()
     lookup_field= 'id'
class ModelTaskView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     serializer_class=ModelTaskSerializer
     queryset = ModelTask.objects.all()
     lookup_field = 'id'
class TaskView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     serializer_Class =TaskSerializer
     queryset = Task.objects.all()
     lookup_field = 'id'
```

Comment: What does the viewset look like? Did you write a custom bulk create method?

Comment: Can you share your `serializers.py` and `views.py`?

Comment: Thank you guys, i just added serializers.py and views.py

Comment: Nobody knows why?